# Download a growing log file continuously via HTTP

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I managed to get data from the target (see code below), but I want to continuously download as the log file on the server is appended to.

```
from importlib.resources import path
import requests
import json
import shutil
import logging

logging.captureWarnings(True)

url = "https://<IP address>/wga/reverseproxy_logging/instance/wga/request.log"

headers = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers, verify=False, auth=('user','password'))
with open('request.log', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
```

Comment: Your code looks fine...what makes you think it is not streaming?  What do you think is happening?  There's clearly no giant file read into memory happening before writing to disk.

Comment: @JohnZwinck thank you
so actually, what do I have to change in my code to get it in realtime, for example the log in the target adds it will add automatically the files that I have monitored using the python code.

Comment: Are you trying to ask "How do I continuously download a file from a web server in a way that every time the file gets longer on the server, my downloaded copy also gets longer?"

Comment: @JohnZwinck, yeah right, that's what i meant

Comment: Can you find out if your server supports HEAD and RANGE requests?  If so, it is possible to download incrementally.  If not, it could be that the only solution is to download the entire file again from time to time.  You can use the requests library to send HEAD and RANGE requests to test your server.

Comment: thank you for recomendation, 
i will try your recomendation @JohnZwinck